# How to stop Python from checking for files upon execution

Tags: python, file, order-of-execution

I've got a script I've put together that generates a number of files full of json data by calling another python module.  I then want to be able to import those after they are generated and do things with the data they contain.

The problem is, when I try to run this script, it complains about the files not existing.  I guess because Python checks for all files to be opened before executing the code, regardless of where the open statements fall within the code.  Is there a way around this, so it won't try to open the files until after the generator has called the module to create them?  Example code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, sys
import json
import random
import ships_levels_stats_generator

def main():
    number = 10
    ships_levels_stats_generator.interface(str(number))

    for i in range(0, number):
        with open('../Test/attack%s.json' % i) as attack_json:
            attack_data = json.load(attack_json)
        with open('../Test/hp%s.json' % i) as hp_json:
            hp_data = json.load(hp_json)
        with open('../Test/repair%s.json' % i) as repair_json:
            repair_data = json.load(repair_json)

    for key in attack_data.iterkeys():
        if len(attack_data[key]) < 20:
            print "Under 20."
        elif len(attack_data[key]) < 30:
            print "Under 30."
        elif len(attack_data[key]) < 60:
            print "Under 50."
        elif len(attack_data[key]) < 80:
            print "Under 80."
        else:
            print "Over 80."
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just an indentation issue: the for loop needs to be indented to be part of your main function. As it is now, it runs when the file is loaded each time.

Comment: Sorry, that's just me not getting the formatting right in this.  It is indented in the actual code.

Comment: @KrisGriebe Then the problem is not in the code you posted. Python doesn't try to open any files until it executes the `open` call, so that's not the issue.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the full code, but it could be a permissions issue, or it could be that the code has a conditional, empty loop, or return so that the open never gets called.

Comment: Interesting, the open statements in the ships_levels_stats_generator look like this: 

        hp_table_file = open('../Test/hp%s.json' % number, 'w')

Comment: Meh, it's because I didn't create the Test directory on this computer, just did a git pull this morning and went at it.  My bad.

Answer (score 0):

You never call  `ships_levels_stats_generator.interface()`, which is presumeably where you create the files, Lose the`def main():`